# How to sum previous rows in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sum, rows

I'm not sure how to correctly word what I want to do, or if this is even possible, so sorry if this sounds confusing and doesn't make sense. What I want to do basically is some way to create a separate column in a dataframe that sums consecutive values. For instance, I have this column, shown below, and I would like a separate column, which contains the sum of 0.00871 and 0.001, and then 0.000603 and 0.0123, and 0.000871 and 4.37E-05, and etc. Does this make sense? If so, is there a way I can code for this, instead of doing it manually? All help is appreciated! I would prefer to do this on Python, but any language would suffice.

[Not allowed to embed the image, so hopefully this works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fp8b8.png)

Comment: Please add sample data as text not as image, and also provide your expected output.

Comment: [pandas cumsum](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- given your data is presented as an image, I have simulated it
- what you state

  1. for every second row `d.index % 2`
  2. sum current row and previous row `d["sourceValue"] + d["sourceValue"].shift()`

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

pd.DataFrame({"sourceValue": np.random.uniform(0, 1, 30)}).assign(
    required=lambda d: np.where(
        d.index % 2, d["sourceValue"] + d["sourceValue"].shift(), np.nan
    )
)
```

|  | sourceValue | required |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0.804529 | nan |
| 1 | 0.24858 | 1.05311 |
| 2 | 0.710556 | nan |
| 3 | 0.415231 | 1.12579 |
| 4 | 0.879645 | nan |
| 5 | 0.599331 | 1.47898 |
| 6 | 0.635365 | nan |
| 7 | 0.587647 | 1.22301 |
| 8 | 0.902475 | nan |
| 9 | 0.0398323 | 0.942307 |
| 10 | 0.357436 | nan |
| 11 | 0.469155 | 0.826591 |
| 12 | 0.732759 | nan |
| 13 | 0.721996 | 1.45476 |
| 14 | 0.030494 | nan |
| 15 | 0.0047623 | 0.0352563 |
| 16 | 0.01081 | nan |
| 17 | 0.130903 | 0.141713 |
| 18 | 0.643588 | nan |
| 19 | 0.837585 | 1.48117 |
| 20 | 0.63328 | nan |
| 21 | 0.506582 | 1.13986 |
| 22 | 0.855085 | nan |
| 23 | 0.100174 | 0.95526 |
| 24 | 0.146992 | nan |
| 25 | 0.64605 | 0.793041 |
| 26 | 0.460859 | nan |
| 27 | 0.818967 | 1.27983 |
| 28 | 0.809294 | nan |
| 29 | 0.664239 | 1.47353 |

#### supplementary - multiple columns

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({f"sourceValue{i+1}": np.random.uniform(0, 1, 30) for i in range(7)})

# static version
df["targetValue1"] = np.where(df.index%2, df["sourceValue1"]+df["sourceValue1"].shift(), np.nan)
df["targetValue2"] = np.where(df.index%2, df["sourceValue2"]+df["sourceValue2"].shift(), np.nan)
df["targetValue3"] = np.where(df.index%2, df["sourceValue3"]+df["sourceValue3"].shift(), np.nan)
df["targetValue4"] = np.where(df.index%2, df["sourceValue4"]+df["sourceValue4"].shift(), np.nan)
df["targetValue5"] = np.where(df.index%2, df["sourceValue5"]+df["sourceValue5"].shift(), np.nan)
df["targetValue6"] = np.where(df.index%2, df["sourceValue6"]+df["sourceValue6"].shift(), np.nan)
df["targetValue7"] = np.where(df.index%2, df["sourceValue7"]+df["sourceValue7"].shift(), np.nan)

# dynamic version
df = df.assign(**{c.replace("source", "target"): 
                  np.where(df.index % 2, df[c] + df[c].shift(), np.nan)
                  for c in df.columns if "sourceValue" in c})

df
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is what I wanted to do.

Comment: Actually, one more thing, there is more than one column in my original table, actually 7, including the numbers shown above, so how could I add this to my original table and then save this separately?

Comment: so you have 7 columns and you want 7 new columns that are calculated in same way?

Comment: I have updated answer - you specifications are a bit ambiguous.  hopefully this is what you are trying to describe.  I've provided in way that it automatically picks up columns (dynamic) and static - more columns more code

Comment: Apologies, I didn't make it clear, I meant that I just wanted the one column to sum that one column, but I want this to be a part of my original dataframe, which has 6 unrelated columns, which I do not want to edit or sum.

Comment: clear as mud ... :-). therefore you just want one of the static lines - maybe?  or maybe use the `assign()` approach as a different data frame `df2 = df.assign(...)`

Answer (score 0):

To get Cumulative Sum, Use -

```
df.cumsum()
```